# LNK1104: cannot open file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\lib.obj'

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019, linker-errors, googletest

I am generating a GoogleTest project for a C++ library in Visual Studio 2019 (Community Version) and created it via the wizard.

I have set Project/Properties/Linker/Additional Dependencies = $(WindowsSdkDir)\lib;
to resolve an initial linker error `(LNK1104: cannot open file 'libcpmtd.lib')`. I now get:

```
1>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\\\lib.obj'
```

How do I resolve this? (I notice a double slash in this path: something needs to be installed? Possibly an environment variable?)

I tried adding /VERBOSE to the command line but got no additional information.

Comment: Why are there a double slash? I suggest you try to change to a single slash. You could refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/tool-errors/linker-tools-error-lnk1104?view=vs-2019) for more information.

Comment: The double-backslash occurs because the macro `$(WindowsSdkDir)` already contains a trailing backslash (so you should use `$(WindowsSdkDir)lib`, not `$(WindowsSdkDir)\lib`). However, the _Additional Dependencies_ field is for specifying individual LIB-files; for folders there is the _Additional Library Directories_ field instead. Also, the problem with `libcpmtd.lib` may be caused by mismatching runtime library build type: perhaps the GoogleTest library was linked to the static debug runtime (see the `mtd` suffix), and your test project is linked to the dynamic debug or even release runtime.

Answer (score -2):

Add The Library to the Path in the Properties Page -> Linker -> General, If You have Added then Try Including it in the Properties Page -> Linker -> Input.
If You dont like using Slashes, Visual Studio has Macros for That, Or else Just Copy and Past the Path.